# Extension configuration missing

Tags: typo3, typo3-extensions, typo3-9.x

Extension configuration is missing for all extensions that should have one. Am I missing a configuration that was introduced in version 9?

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7mLGF.png)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The Extension Configuration, which was formerly found in the *Extension Manager*, has moved with the release of TYPO3 v9.

You can change the configuration of extensions now in the new TYPO3 Backend module **ADMIN TOOLS > Settings**. It's the first box in the list, the title is still the same.